# How to sort the inode count from largest to smallest

Tags: shell, sorting, inode

I am using below code to show inode and disk space. It is working fine but I want to sort the count from largest to smallest. What changes do I need to make?

I tried to add `sort | uniq -c | sort -rn` but it's not working.

```
for DIR in `find $CURDIR -maxdepth 1 -type d |grep -xv $CURDIR |sort`; do
    COUNT=$(GET_COUNT $DIR)
    SIZE=$(GET_SIZE $DIR)

    # Check if exclude arg was used, and if so only output directories above exclude inode count
    if [[ -z $exclude ]] || [[ -n $exclude && $COUNT -gt $exclude ]]
    then
        printf "$format" "  $COUNT" "  $SIZE" "`basename $DIR`"
    fi
```

I need to get the inode and disk size count from largest to smallest.

Comment: What do you mean "its not working"?  If you have unsorted data and you pipe it to `sort`, it will be sorted.  Given that you have not shown what `GET_COUNT` or `GET_SIZE` do, or what your current output is, nor why you aren't just using `df`, it's hard to say why you cannot just pipe your data to `sort`.

Comment: https://github.com/tripflex/inodes/blob/master/inodes I am using this bash script. but when I try to add  uniq -c | sort -rn in existing script, I get error as below: du: cannot access ‘      1 /home/new/cache’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing each folder in a loop, considering combining leveraging 'find ... -printf', combining it with proper expression to filter (for the exclusion rule)

```
find $CURDIR -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 - type d -links +${exclude-0} -printf '%n %s %f\n'
```

Where

- mindepth will exclude the top directory,
- ${exclude-0} will force the force the expression to be numeric  (resulting in '-links +0', if exclude is not set).
- printf used to output link count, file size (bytes) and base file name.

For example:

```
exclude=2
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d  -links +${exclude+0} -printf '%n %s %f\n' 

Output:
3 4096 a
3 4096 b
```